# Single authentication for multiple grails projects

Tags: session, authentication, grails, spring-security

So, I have multiple grails apps, but I'd like to package them into a single mega app that manages user login, permissions, which appscan they access, etc. I can already links to the other apps depending on the logged in users role.

I'm using Spring Security with all of the apps, and they already share a database for users and roles. The problem I'm having is that I want the users to be instantly logged in on all of the apps when they log in into the "mega app", I want them all to share a login session.

Right now, I have a login for the users to access the "mega app" where they are linked to the other apps, but they have to manually log in again for each of the different grails apps they are linked to. And I don't like this, I want all apps to share a session, atleast for login. Any way to do this?

Having all the source from all the apps inside one single grails project is not a possibility here, it would be too heavy and some users don't even install all of the apps, since this is installed on their own private servers for them to use in their own local network. Also, login sessions time out after a while of not being used, making the problem even worse.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The [spring-security-cas](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-cas) plugin is one option; it uses the open source [CAS single sign-on server](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home) to let you authenticate to any server and be automatically authenticated on all of the others.